# Guidelines for Opera Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

Opera Mobile fails to render two sites I help out with correctly and I cannot find the guidelines for Opera Mobile.

All other browsers tested (even Opera for the Wii) show these sites correctly.

There is an [emulator](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mobile-10-widgets-mobile-emulator-desktop/) to help development but it is impossible to help the browser work correctly without knowing the rules.

Do things have to be presented to the client differently?, are there limitations on certain elements?, does JavaScript suffer from race conditions?, etc... or is there a universal "please use Safari Mobile" campaign in the same vein as the dump "Internet Explorer 6" efforts?

Comment: Possibly helpful: featurelist http://www.opera.com/mobile/features/#specs of Opera Mobile vs Opera Mini 4 and Opera Mini 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at what's supported generally in this [Opera Standards Chart](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2010/03/16/opera-standards-chart).

My experience of the Opera Browsers. mostly with Mini 4 and 5, was that they worked pretty well for a tiny browser on a non-smartphone. Very-long pages with lots of content did not work terribly well, and I found I had to make sure not to scroll before all content loaded otherwise the browser would blank screen on me. Also, sites with odd ajax-based or otherwise peculiar security schemes could be difficult to log into.

[**dev.opera.com**](http://dev.opera.com/) appears to be a good resource, though it's kind of got a whole kitchen sink of information. I'm not seeing a simple "target Opera Mobile for developers" document.

Comment: The chart was enough to help (no web font!) thank you.